# Общий член простых предложений

Tags: запятые

Таким образом, Газали, чье имя известно во всем мире(,) и чья слава распространилась по всему свету, происходил из бедной семьи.
Нужна ли запятая в скобках, или "Таким образом" является общим членом двух простых предложений в составе сложного?
*На сайте эта фраза есть без запятой, но этот сайт не аргумент.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нужна ли запятая в скобках, или "Таким образом" является общим членом
> двух простых предложений в составе сложного?

*Для начала: в Вашем вопросе запятая тоже не нужна. ))) Это вопросительное ССП.*

По сути же вопрос задан не совсем верно.
"Таким образом" не относится к придаточным и общим членом служить не может, но запятая тем не менее скорее всего не нужна. Причина в том, что эти придаточные выглядят однородными и соединенными союзом "И" (см. - Серж).
Так что на сайте как минимум - не ошибка.

*В порядке обсуждения.*
Вопрос, скорее в другом: будет ли ошибкой написание с запятой. И вот тут ответить наверняка не могу. Дело в том, что однородность придаточных не совсем очевидна - невозможно подобрать общий для обоих придаточных вопрос к основной части, по смыслу они отвечают на вопрос "Кто?" или "Какой?", но грамматика у них другая. Так что, если автору очень хочется, полагаю, запятую можно оставить как "авторский" знак.
Но если такого желания нет, то лучше, конечно, без запятой.

*(+) Не поленился, нашел этот текст. Он грамотно написан в целом, причин для оригинальной авторской пунктуации там не просматривается. Так что запятой там действительно не нужно. Мою реплику о возможности запятой можно отнести к чисто умозрительным рассуждениям. Но возник другой вопрос, уместно ли там использование "таким образом" - возможно, это и вызвало затруднение у автора вопроса. По контексту этот оборот не относится к биографии персонажа, он означает, что автор установил этот факт исходя из вышеприведенных фактов. Надо бы так: "Таким образом установлено, что...." - ну и в таком виде становится очевидным, что это "таким образом" никаким образом не связано с придаточными.*

Comment: "Для начала: в Вашем вопросе запятая тоже не нужна. ))) Это вопросительное ССП". Спасибо огромное! Это для меня "открытие"!

Answer (score 2):

Запятая в вашем примере не нужна. В данном случае перед нами однородные придаточные, соединенные союзом и.
Ср.: Получили известие, **что Волга стала** и **что через нее потянулись обозы** (Акс.).

Общий второстепенный член, о котором Вы  говорите, бывает в ССП.
Ср.: **В такую минуту** и волк не рыщет и медведь и вылезает из берлоги.

В ССП может быть и общее придаточное предложение.

**Когда выглянет солнце,** лужи быстро просохнут мы снова пойдем гулять в парк.